# RTCPeerConnection signaling library

Tags: javascript, node.js, library-design, socket

I created a library/npm module to handle the signaling process for `RTCPeerConnection`. There is still a good bit of work that needs done (error handling, dealing with users disconnecting during the signaling process, etc.), but at the moment I am mostly looking for suggestions/ideas about the overall architecture.

Here is the [Github repo](https://github.com/traviswimer/SignalFire.js).

Below I have included the module for the server-side and the script for the client-side.

**Server-Side:**

```
var io = require('socket.io');
module.exports = function () {
  // Is used to give each peer a unique ID
  var peerIdCounter = 0;
  // create next ID and return it
  var incrementPeerIdCounter = function () {
    peerIdCounter++;
    return peerIdCounter;
  };
  //  //  //  //  /
  /////////////////
  // Peer Object //
  /*****************************************************************************/
  var createPeer = function (socket) {
    /////////////////////////////////////
    // Peer Object's Private Variables //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                              //
    var self;
    var id;
    // holds the peerConnect offer for this peer
    var offer;
    // list of peers that can connect
    var connectingPeers = {};
    // The Peer class

    function Peer(socket) {
      this.socket = socket;
      id = incrementPeerIdCounter();
      self = this;
      // listen for client sending offer
      self.socket.on('clientSendingOffer', receiveOfferFromClient);
      // detect receiving an answer from clietn
      self.socket.on('clientSendingAnswer', receiveAnswerFromClient);
      // listen for ice candidates
      self.socket.on('clientSendingIce', receiveIceCandidate);
    }
    //                                              //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////
    // Peer Object's Public Methods //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                              //
    // Initiates signaling process
    Peer.prototype.connectToPeer = function (peer, successCallback, failCallback) {
      // answering peer starts waiting for an offer
      peer.acceptOfferFrom(self);
      // This peer will make an offer
      this.makeOfferRequest(peer);
    };
    // Request a peerConnection offer from the current peer
    Peer.prototype.makeOfferRequest = function (peer) {
      // add peer to list of accepted requests
      connectingPeers[peer.getPeerId()] = peer;
      // ask client for an offer
      self.socket.emit('serverRequestingOffer', {
        peerId: peer.getPeerId()
      });
    };
    // Accept peerConnection offers from the specified peer
    Peer.prototype.acceptOfferFrom = function (peer) {
      // add peer to list of accepted requests
      connectingPeers[peer.getPeerId()] = peer;
    };
    // getter for the peer ID
    Peer.prototype.getPeerId = function () {
      return id;
    };
    //                                              //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////
    // Peer Object's Private Methods //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                              //
    // Handle an offer sent from the client
    var receiveOfferFromClient = function (data) {
      offer = data.offer;
      sendOfferToClient(data.peerId);
    };
    // Send offer to the other peer
    var sendOfferToClient = function (peerId) {
      connectingPeers[peerId].socket.emit(
        'serverSendingOffer', {
        peerId: self.getPeerId(),
        offer: offer
      });
    };
    // Send answer to initiating peer
    var receiveAnswerFromClient = function (data) {
      var peerId = data.peerId;
      data.peerId = self.getPeerId();
      connectingPeers[peerId].socket.emit('serverSendingAnswer', data);
    };
    //Handle ICE candidates received
    var receiveIceCandidate = function (data) {
      var iceInfo = {
        peerId: self.getPeerId(),
        candidate: data.candidate
      };
      connectingPeers[data.peerId].socket.emit('serverSendingIce', iceInfo);
    };
    //                                              //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Return an instance of the Peer class
    return new Peer(socket);
  };
  /*____________________________________________________________________________*/
  //  //  //  //  //  //  //  /
  /////////////////////////////
  // Module's Public Methods //
  /*****************************************************************************/
  // Initiates listening for signaling requests
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
  var listen = function (port, successCallback, failCallback) {
    if(typeof port != 'number') {
      return false;
    }
    // Handle socket requests
    /////////////////////////////
    var server = io.listen(port);
    server.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      var peer;
      try {
        peer = createPeer(socket);
      } catch(e) {
        failCallback(e);
      } finally {
        successCallback(peer);
      }
    });
    return server;
  };
  // Return the public methods
  return {
    listen: listen
  };
  /*____________________________________________________________________________*/
}();
```

**Client-side**

```
(function () {
  var signalfire = function () {
    //  //  //  //  /
    /////////////////
    // Peer Object //
    /*****************************************************************************/
    var createPeer = function (socket, options) {
      /////////////////////////////////////
      // Peer Object's Private Variables //
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //                                              //
      var self;
      //holds the ids of the peers that are connecting
      var connectingPeers = {};
      // holds function to call when server requests a connection offer
      // or provides a connection offer
      var makeRTCPeer = options.connector || function () {};
      // holds function to call when signaling process is complete
      var signalingComplete = options.onSignalingComplete || function () {};
      // The Peer class

      function Peer(socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        self = this;
        // listen for server requesting offer
        self.socket.on('serverRequestingOffer', sendOfferToServer);
        // detect receiving an offer from server
        self.socket.on('serverSendingOffer', sendAnswerToServer);
        // listen for ice candidates
        self.socket.on('serverSendingAnswer', receiveAnswerFromServer);
        // listen for ice candidates
        self.socket.on('serverSendingIce', receiveIceCandidate);
      }
      //                                              //
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////
      ///////////////////////////////////
      // Peer Object's Private Methods //
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////
      //                                              //
      // Receive offer request and return an offer
      var sendOfferToServer = function (data) {
        // create RTCPeerConnection
        var rtcPeerConnection = makeRTCPeer();
        // initialize ice candidate listeners
        iceSetup(rtcPeerConnection, data);
        // Add connection to list of peers
        connectingPeers[data.peerId] = rtcPeerConnection;
        // create offer and send to server
        rtcPeerConnection.createOffer(function (offerResponse) {
          data.offer = offerResponse;
          rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offerResponse, function () {
            socket.emit('clientSendingOffer', data);
          });
        });
      };
      // Receive peer offer from server. Return an answer.
      var sendAnswerToServer = function (data) {
        // create RTCPeerConnection
        var rtcPeerConnection = makeRTCPeer();
        // initialize ice candidate listeners
        iceSetup(rtcPeerConnection, data);
        // Add connection to list of peers
        connectingPeers[data.peerId] = rtcPeerConnection;
        // Create description from offer received
        var offer = new RTCSessionDescription(data.offer);
        // Set Description, create answer, send answer to server
        rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer, function () {
          rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer(function (answer) {
            rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            var answerData = {
              peerId: data.peerId,
              answer: answer
            };
            socket.emit('clientSendingAnswer', answerData);
          });
        });
      };
      // Receive peer answer from server
      var receiveAnswerFromServer = function (data) {
        var peerConn = connectingPeers[data.peerId];
        var answer = new RTCSessionDescription(data.answer);
        peerConn.setRemoteDescription(answer, function () {});
      };
      // receive ice candidates from server
      var receiveIceCandidate = function (data) {
        if(data.candidate !== null) {
          connectingPeers[data.peerId].addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data.candidate));
        }
      };
      // setup ice candidate handling
      var iceSetup = function (rtcPeerConnection, data) {
        // check if connection has been created
        rtcPeerConnection.onicechange = function (evt) {
          if(rtcPeerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'connected') {
            signalingComplete(rtcPeerConnection);
          }
        };
        // listen for ice candidates and send to server
        rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = function (iceData) {
          var sendingIceInfo = {
            peerId: data.peerId,
            candidate: iceData.candidate
          };
          socket.emit('clientSendingIce', sendingIceInfo);
        };
      };
      //                                              //
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // Return an instance of the Peer class
      return new Peer(socket);
    };
    /*____________________________________________________________________________*/
    //  //  //  //  //  
    ////////////////////
    // Public Methods //
    /*****************************************************************************/
    var connect = function (options, successCallback, failCallback) {
      /*
        Options:
            "server" - The url + port of the server to connect to
            "connector" - A function that is called when the server requests
                        an RTC offer. Must return an RTCPeerConnction object.
        */
      if(typeof options != 'object') {
        return false;
      }
      var socket = io.connect(options.server, {
        'force new connection': true
      });
      socket.on('connect', function () {
        var peer;
        try {
          peer = createPeer(socket, options);
        } catch(e) {
          failCallback(e);
        } finally {
          successCallback(peer);
        }
      });
      socket.on('connect_error', function (e) {
        failCallback(e);
      });
      return socket;
    };
    return {
      connect: connect
    };
    /*____________________________________________________________________________*/
  };
  // set the signalfire global variable
  window.signalfire = signalfire();
}());
```

Answer (score 2):

Interesting code,

I am somewhat surprised that you assign `connectToPeer` to `Peer.prototype`. A distinct `Peer` function object will be created with each call of `createPeer`, which makes it pointless to assign anything to the `prototype`. This means also from a memory perspective, that each connected peer has it's own closure with all the code in `createPeer`. I think you are doing this because you want the private functions, I am not convinced that it is worth it.

Furthermore I am surprised that you call `successCallback` in `finally`, which means it also gets called in case of failure, which is not intuitive.

There is clearly common code between the client and the server, you should extract that common code.

Other than that, your code is well commented and fairly easy to follow, and JsHint has nothing to complain about.